# Why are these nul's appearing

Tags: c#, filestream

I used to write to a lot of different files using the following function

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Settings.PsLog, FileMode.Truncate, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 1024, FileOptions.None, null))
{
    foreach (string line in checkList)
    {
        byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(line + Environment.NewLine);
        await fs.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, line.Length);
    }
}
```

As this code was copy pasted all about, I decided to extract it to a more general function.

```
private static async Task WriteTextAsync(string filePath, string text)  
{
    byte[] encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text + Environment.NewLine);
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
           FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write,
           bufferSize: 1024, useAsync: true))
    {
        await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length);
    };
}
```

However after using the extracted version random NUL's are appended to the text

[image]

Where are these nulls coming from? I tried copying the `filestream()` settings 1 on 1 as well, but even then the NUL's occurred.

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` is a UTF-16 encoding. Inspect the `byte` array, it should contain a number of `0` bytes. Use `Encoding.UTF8` instead.

Comment: @JeanHominal Seems to be the case. But how come function A does not have a problem with this, and function B does. Even though the same input is given, and the same steps are taken?

Comment: This should always have been added the NUL's (in fact you add them explicitly). Perhaps it looked right before when you truncated the file because the encoding was auto-detected (you can test this by opening it in a hex editor), but the other way you append it onto a file, which maybe has an UTF8 BOM (again check in a hex editor) and anyway starts with a bunch of plain ascii, which would fool readers about the format

Comment: @harold Function A does not add them. No sign of them in hex either, the screenshot included is from notepad++ whilst in ansii encoding. you can also clearly see the transition. Even while inspecting the byte array in visual studio, no signs of the nul's in the first function, they do clearly show up in function B

Comment: Function A should be writing only partial lines, it's writing the string length amount of bytes, not the byte array length amount of bytes.

Comment: @codran Thats actually a good catch, thanks

Comment: @mx-d: Could you please post an input string which does not output `NUL` bytes for the first code block but which does output `NUL` output bytes for the second code block so that the cause of that issue can be confirmed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code is broken.

When `Encoding.Unicode` is used, `line.Length` is not the same thing as `encodedText.Length`. When you try to write the data, you only write about half of it (on average).

Since that doesn't actually happen in your example, the most likely reason is that you're not actually using `Encoding.Unicode`, but rather either `Encoding.UTF8` or one of the single-byte ANSI/ASCII encodings.

In either case, make sure you write as much bytes as there are to write. The number of characters is irrelevant. And make sure you use the proper encoding - there can only be one.

As a side-note, your code is going to be much slower than the original as well. This is most probably a poor trade-off. Instead, you might want to capture the whole `foreach`, and pass `IEnumerable<string>` instead of just `string`. If you really only need to write a single string in some cases, you can supply a `params string` overload or whatever suits you best. And do make sure that all cases are actually equivalent - this one surely isn't, since the original file is discarded in the original code, while it's only ever appended to in your code.

Comment: `line.Length` was indeed the culprit. wrote the unicode encoded string in utf8 format, without losing any characters (besides the nul's that is)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're writing UTF-16 output?

Elaboration:

In both the first and seconds blocks of code in your question you are using `Encoding.Unicode`, which encodes strings to [little endian UTF-16 byte representations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx).  Little endian byte order UTF-16 representations of ASCII characters such as `0` or `G` contain the usual ASCII byte as the first byte, then `0` (`NUL`) as the second byte of the character.  This is the likely source of the `NUL` bytes in the output.

As for why `NUL` did not appear in the output from the first block of code I am not sure.  Please post an input string which does not output `NUL` bytes for the first code block but which does output `NUL` output bytes for the second code block so that the cause of that issue can be confirmed.

Comment: Considering I am converting it to a unicode encoding. Only numbers and letters are included in the writes, and only one of the functions adds the nul's  I do kind of doubt that

Comment: Hmm... I'll have a deeper. look later. Thanks.

Comment: @codran Jeans comment just pointed that out as well, still wondering why function A does not add the nul's even though the same encoding is used. whilst function B does add them.

Comment: @MXD the first function should have the same issue, but it may be more noticeable in the second case because it appears that you know have a mixed-coding file. Try opening the file created by the first function in a hex editor, you should see the nul bytes there.

Comment: Not a critique or a question. His question was "Where are these nulls coming from?" My posted answer suggests what I believed the answer to be. Based on subsequent discussion, @Jean Hominal's twice upvoted comment and the accepted answer UTF-16 was likely the cause of the outputted NUL's.

Comment: My answer may not be high quality, but it did answer the question, correctly, and at a point in time at which no one else has answered. Oh well. :)

Comment: I've added a detailed elaboration to my original answer to make it more clearly an answer to the original asker's question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing bufferSize. You should see if there's a difference in where the nul starts inserting after changing.

Also not sure what happened between a for loop running through all the lines to just a single method producing results. You don't have multiple threads running at the same time going to this file right?

Comment: By increasing the buffer size of the first function the same issue occurs. All running from a single thread, multi threaded IO operations only slow it down :)